# updating a mysql table with a large csv file in PHP

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have a CSV file which has approximately 13000 lines to be updated into a mysql database.
My PHP function stops after about 5000 lines with a timeout or memory overflow.

It loops every line with fgetcsv and checks if the line exists already, which is causing the timeout i guess (SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE queries).

I can't drop the table and re-insert everything because the table still has relations with other tables. -> Then i could write a single INSERT statement with multiple value strings in blocks of e.g. 5000 lines.

I need to find a way to read the file in chunks to prevent a timeout.

Thx in advance!

Some code:

```
private function readFile()
    {
        $this->profiler = NULL;
        $this->auto_render = FALSE;
        $this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

        if (array_key_exists('uploadedfile', $_FILES))
        {
            $filename = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
            if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'] == 'application/vnd.ms-excel') // csv file
            {
                if (is_uploaded_file($filename)) //check if file 
                {
                    if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) //check no errors
                    {                   
                        // time limit : unlimited
                        set_time_limit(0);

                        // file handler
                        $filepointer = fopen($filename,'r');
                        return $filepointer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Within another function i call readFile() and loop the lines like this:

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($filepointer, 1000, ";")) != false)
```

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0)` will disable the PHP timeout.

Comment: try adding the beginning of your function these instructions:
`set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "1024M");`

Comment: try this link I believe this person has a problem similar to yours with updating the mysql table with csv file in php http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-185657.html

Comment: You could probably reduce the number of queries (having to SELECT, and INSERT/UPDATE) with a simple REPLACE query.

Comment: i have added `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0)` and `ini_set("memory_limit", "1024M");` -> the script runs longer, but i don't get a response back

I will also look into the REPLACE statement tomorrow, which could reduce some execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Run php file from command line. By default it doesn't have set timeout.
Or increase timeout in `php.ini`.